# JQuery specific variable from a php printed table

Tags: php, jquery, html

Ive got a table with buttons:
[image]

and Ive set specific ID's to each one but I dont see how I can access them all from a JQuery script so i can set a specific get to each one of them.

**Edit:**

All of the buttons have unique ids:
[image]

Shown in google chrome inspect element : 
[image]

When I click REMOVE i want the row to get removed. I can do this and have done this with PHP via GET however I dont want to have to refresh the page every time I remove one. I tested doing it with JQuery .GET and it works fine however I dont want to have to make a new script to have to delete every single row, rather do it dynamically by getting the ID of the row and removing the row that the REMOVE button is in. Ive tried multiple ways of doing this but all I do is fail.

This is the script that prints the data in the table

```
function print_data($info1,$info2,$info3,$info4,$info5,$info6,$info7,$info8){
    echo"<tr><td id='notice1id$info8'>$info1</td><td id='noticename$info8'>$info2</td><td id='noticetype$info8'>$info3</td><td id='noticecontent$info8'>$info4</td><td id='noticeshow$info8'>$info5</td><td id='noticeedit$info8'><a href='admincp.php?edit=1&editid=$info6'><div class='btn btn-success'>Edit</div></a></td><td id='noticeremove$info8'><input type='button' id='remove$info8' value='remove' onclick='removeMe();' class='btn btn-danger' name='$info8'></td><td style='display:none;'><p id='getid' name='$info8' style='display:none;'></p></td><td style='display:none;'><script> function removeMe() {    alert($info8);}</script></td><input id='noticeid$info7' class='form-control' style='display:none;' type='text'  name='$info8' value=$info7></td></tr>";
?><?php
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    print_data($row['NoticeID'],$row['NoticeName'],$row['NoticeType'],$row['NoticeContent'],$row['NoticeShow'],$row['NoticeID'],$row['NoticeID'],$row['NoticeID']);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = $("#getid").attr("name");
    alert("#remove" + id);
    $("#remove" + id).click(function () {
        var getcontent = $("#noticeid4").val();
        $("#notice1id5,#noticename5,#noticetype5,#noticecontent5,#noticeshow5,#noticeedit5,#noticeremove5").slideUp(300, function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So where is your Code? What have you tried?

Comment: Edited w/ the code. I cant think of a way of doing it without  making a new function for EVERY single new id.

Comment: I dont see how I can access them all from a JQuery script so i can set a specific .get to each one of them.

Comment: does `$('input[id^="noticeid"]')` somehow not work ?

Comment: Could you also add the JavaScript/jQuery you've written to the question/